# Mixed Sharing Model

Tags: sharing

I have a challenge that I can't solve. We have 2 custom objects; Providers and Prescriptions. There is a master-detail relationship between them. Our users are granted access to individual providers via territory shares and consequently the prescriptions because of the master-detail.

We want to be able to hide prescription records of providers that have a certain privacy flag, but also need the counts of those same prescriptions to roll up to reports and dashboards for the user. The user's quotas are measured from the prescriptions, but a certain privacy program prevents the user from being able to see if the providers has written a prescription.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated as I can't seem to solve this one.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately we cannot have different sharing in detail object. 
My firt suggestion would be to change relationship to lookup and use something like this from Andrew for rollup - http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/07/07/new-tool-declarative-rollups-for-lookups/

If you cannot change relationship because of some constrain then,
You can remove related list and use inline VF page and override View button of "Prescriptions" to hide details of record if someone clicks on URL directly. However risk here is that user can report on fields and fields can be accessible from API's which is not recommended.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Jitendra. That's a good suggestion, but the user would still be able to run a report on providers and their related prescriptions because of the lookup. I'm trying to prevent them from seeing any prescriptions under a provider where the provider is marked as private. So, to clarify, if the user is looking at the provider detail and that provider is flagged as private, there shouldn't be any related prescriptions records. BUT, they need to somehow see how may prescriptions were written in their territory in both report and dashboard format. Sorry if I'm not clear.

Comment: Hi Adam, If we change relationship to lookup then we can control visibility of related prescriptions using Sharing rules.

Comment: The user would need a share to see both the provider and the Rx correct? If so, the lookup between the two would allow the user to run a report "Providers with Prescriptions" and see the provider with their related Rxs. Correct? Thank you for your continued help.

Comment: Yeah, Thats right. If we can control record visibility they can still run report but cannot see records if its not shared with them.